# Excel - sum numbers in each cell, that matches the pattern

Tags: excel

I have a table for capacity management, that contains information about teams working on project in time. I would like to be able to create a new table, that would basically tell me, which team is overloaded. I guess example would explain it better:

Here is simplified table 1

[image]

The number indicates how many resources is needed from the team on given day

Here is the second table, that I need

[image]

The numbers in columns is sum of all numbers for the team for the specific day across all projects.

Is this somehow possible? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a summary table with the dates in the column headers and the team names in the row headers. Then you can use a SumProduct() formula to calculate the totals per team and date. Refer to the screenshot below.

The formula in cell B13 is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$H$1=B$12)*($A$2:$A$8=$A13)*$B$2:$H$8)
```

Copy across and down. The summary table can be on a different sheet. Just make sure that you get the references right and pay attention to the placements of the $ signs.

[image]